# Joomla 3.4.4 ordering Next/Previous Article

Tags: joomla

I have problem with Joomla 3.4.4. I have some articles at tutorial category ex:

1.Tutorial1

2.Tutorial2

3.Tutorial3

2.Tutorial2 and 3.Tutorial3 made by SAVE AS COPY from 1.Tutorial1.

When 1.Tutorial1 opened, in the bottom page next link go to 3.Tutorial3 previous link go to 2.Tutorial2.

**EXPECTED**:

When 1.Tutorial1 opened, in the bottom page next link go to 2.Tutorial2

And When 2.Tutorial2 opened, in the bottom page previous link go to 1.Tutorial1 and next link go to 3.Tutorial3

Already set:

**Category Order** : Title Alphabetical

**Article Order** : Title Alphabetical

Problem Still Exist. Could you tell me how to set joomla config to get like **EXPECTED**

Thanks

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a "category blog" type layout for your menu, you should set your article order to "article order" and then order your articles in article manager accordingly.

Comment: So we must add a menu to configure "category blog" type like you  said. Sorry because I am not using menu before. After adding menu for related category and set Article order to "Title Alphabetical", problem fixed. When tested to UNPUBLISHED the menu, problem appear again. Thanks for your solution